# This random variable converges in distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

$\delta_x$ is a Borel probability that $\delta_x(x)=1$ and $\mu_n$ is a uniform distribution in this interval $(1, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$

The variable $X_n\sim \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\mu_n$ converges in distribution?

Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: In general i tought that i can calculate the $F_ {X_n }(x)$ and then use the convergence in distribution definition. But I don't interpret $\delta_x (x)=1$

Comment: $\delta_x$ is a measure which has the property that $\delta_x(B)=1$ whenever $x \in B$ and $\delta_x(B)=0$ whenever $x \notin B$.

Comment: ok, but $\frac{1}{ 2}\delta_{\frac{ 1 }{ n}}$ what is?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} \delta_{\frac{1}{n}}(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ whenver $\frac{1}{n} \in B$ and $\frac{1}{2} \delta_{\frac{1}{n}}(B) = 0$ whenver $\frac{1}{n} \notin B$ for any set $B$.

Comment: ok! sorry for my little experience, thanks!